# How to call function in ViewController.m from AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    UIViewController* root = _window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)root;


    UIViewController  mycontroller = (UIViewController )[[navController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    [mycontroller serverSync];
}
```

I use this code, but get error:

ld: 110 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How to fix?

Comment: User NsnotificationCenter for call that method in appdelegates.m file

Comment: You can post notification from appdelegate and addObserver in your viewcontroller. it is better way.

Answer (score 2):

`110 duplicate symbols` means you have a lot more problems than trying to call your view controller's `serverSync` function from your app delegate.

Instead of doing `serverSync` within your app delegate, put it in your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method.

Even better, create a singleton object that does the `serverSync` and your view controller can access and use your server data from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotificationCenter for this. Here is the example.

In your AppDelgate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"iOStpoint.wordpress.com"
     object:self];
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

In your ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:)
                                                 name:@"iOStpoint.wordpress.com"
                                               object:nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"iOStpoint.wordpress.com"])
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");
}
```